# SQL Loop Executing after intended

Tags: plsql

I am attempting to run this code, I know the elements of the Loop are working, and I know the update statement does update. When I run the script with some print statements, it prints the UPDATE information first, then the LOOP information, therefore the update has no information.

```
PROCEDURE UpdateGridStats(p_grid_name VARCHAR2, p_region_name VARCHAR2) IS
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT grd.globalid grid_globalid, wp.globalid workpoint_globalid, wp.feature_class_name workpoint_fcname,
            tt.work_order_task_type task_type_name
    FROM workorderpoint_evw wp, rpt_grid grd, workordertasktype_evw tt 
    WHERE grd.grid_name = p_grid_name
    AND wp.work_order_task_type_globalid = tt.globalid
    AND grd.rpt_region = p_region_name
    AND sde.st_relation_operators.st_within_f(wp.shape, grd.shape) = 1;
    v_count NUMBER := 0;
    v_pole_insp_count NUMBER := 0;
    v_pole_damage_count NUMBER := 0;
    v_cond_damage_count NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR work_rec IN c1
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        v_count := v_count + 1;

        IF work_rec.task_type_name = 'Pole Inspection'
        THEN
            v_pole_insp_count := v_pole_insp_count + 1;
        END IF;
        IF work_rec.task_type_name = 'Pole Damage'
        THEN
            v_pole_damage_count := v_pole_damage_count + 1;
        END IF;        

      EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('==> No data found for work record '); 
      END;
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_pole_damage_count || ',' ||v_pole_insp_count);
    UPDATE rpt_grid grd SET da_pole_count = v_pole_damage_count, ins_structure_count = v_pole_insp_count
    WHERE grd.grid_name = p_grid_name
    AND grd.rpt_region = p_region_name;
    

END UpdateGridStats;
```

Comment: SQL is a set-based language.  You don't "loop" you data.

Comment: I'd consider rewriting as a set based operation if possible, performance tends to be poor for the RBAR approach.

Comment: This is not **SQL**, but Oracle's programming language **PL/SQL**. I've changed the tags for you. The update could be done in a simple SQL update statement, but you are using a stored procedure instead. This stored procedure could still merely contain the simple update statement, but you are using a cursor and a loop instead. Now, what exactly is the problem with the code? I don't understand it. What does happen and what should happen instead?

Comment: Thank you Thornsten, I am attempting to Update a table based on the counts that are produced in the Loop e.g. grid name "1" has DA_POLE_COUNT equal to the returned count and so on. I can get the loop to add to the counts, but the update does not use those values, and always updates 0.

Comment: So, `dbms_output` shows numbers like `12,5`, but instead of updating the row with the values 12 and 5 , the row gets updated with the values 0 and 0?

Comment: Some side notes: **(1)** You will never get a NO_DATA_FOUND exception. The loop is simply run through as often as there are rows in the cursor result, i.e. zero times when there are zero rows matching. **(2)** You are using an ancient join syntax, we used in the 1980s for the lack of something better. In 1992 explicit joins where introduced in standard SQL, and you should only use these, e.g. `FROM workorderpoint_evw wp INNER JOIN rpt_grid grd ON sde.st_relation_operators.st_within_f(wp.shape, grd.shape) = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just forgot to **commit** your changes?

Here is a simpler version of your stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_grid_stats(p_grid_name VARCHAR2, p_region_name VARCHAR2)
IS
  v_ins_structure_count  rpt_grid.ins_structure_count%TYPE;
  v_da_pole_count        rpt_grid.da_pole_count%TYPE;
BEGIN
  UPDATE rpt_grid grd 
  SET (ins_structure_count, da_pole_count) =
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(CASE WHEN tt.work_order_task_type = 'Pole Inspection' THEN 1 END),
      COUNT(CASE WHEN tt.work_order_task_type = 'Pole Damage' THEN 1 END)
    FROM workorderpoint_evw wp
    JOIN workordertasktype_evw tt ON wp.work_order_task_type_globalid = tt.globalid
    WHERE sde.st_relation_operators.st_within_f(wp.shape, grd.shape) = 1
  )
  WHERE grd.grid_name = p_grid_name
  AND grd.rpt_region = p_region_name
  RETURNING ins_structure_count, da_pole_count
       INTO v_ins_structure_count, v_da_pole_count;

  dbms_output.put_line(
    SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows got updated. Values: ' ||
    'ins_structure_count = ' || v_ins_structure_count ||
    ', da_pole_count = ' || v_da_pole_count
  );

  COMMIT;
END update_grid_stats;
```

The variables and the `RETURNING` clause are merely needed for the output. If you don't need the output, you can remove them.

Answer (score -1):

if I understand correcatally, the proc works OK, but the print statemnts are not. I beleve the print operations are on a different thread. To overcome this issue, try to replace your pront statment with raiserror function :

```
declare @mag varchar(max) = 'Hllo world'
raiserror ( @ERR_MSG ,0, 1) with nowait;
```